# How can I use a wireless SD card (like EyeFi) to save photos to a network share?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard, wireless

I am wondering if a wireless SD card exists that can be setup to copy photos from the card to a file share through an existing wireless network.

Basically I want the process of getting the photos from my camera to my Synology NAS which host the file share to be automated without having to tether my camera or SD Card. I do not like the idea of having to connect to an *ad hoc* network that some of the wireless SD cards provide.

If anyone can think of another way to get my photos from my camera to my NAS I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, apparently, a python Eyefi server that you can run on your NAS, which allows you to use an older eyefi card in the way you describe. (The current Mobi cards can only do ad hoc networking).

See:

- http://thijs.elenbaas.net/2013/03/installing-an-eye-fi-server-on-a-synology-nas/

Comment: You could run this is something like a Raspberry Pi making it even more lightweight

Comment: Good point regarding the Raspberry Pi!